# How would a std::optional<std::nullopt_t> operate?

Tags: c++, c++17, stdoptional

Kind of a silly question, but I'm curious and I haven't found this explained.  Is it legal to construct a `std::optional<std::nullopt_t>`?  If you did, what would

```cpp
std::optional<std::nullopt_t> x(std::nullopt);
```

do?  Would `x` contain a value or not?

Comment: [It's not allowed](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional): _"In addition, a program is ill-formed if it instantiates an optional with the (possibly cv-qualified) tag types `std::nullopt_t` or `std::in_place_t`."_

Comment: [live link to gcc error](https://wandbox.org/permlink/E3Kb8KmDEJdCp7Q7)

Comment: *Is it legal to construct...* Human sacrifice! Dogs and cats living together! Mass hysteria!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, instantiating a `optional` with `nullopt_t` (or `in_place_t`) is explicitly forbidden and will fail with a compile error.

Comment: https://eel.is/c++draft/optional#optional.general-3